# Как создать собственные элементы управления, отвечающие за смену типа карт?

Tags: google-maps, карты, android, java

Добрый день!

В xml добавлена `MapView` и три кнопки для переключения режима карты. В `Activity` в `onCreate` установлен начальный вид отображения карты вот таким образом:

```
mapView.setSatellite(true);
```

Но это не подходит для смены отображения по нажатию кнопок, так как есть только `setTraffic`, `setStreet` и `setSatellite`.

Нашла метод `setMapType(int type)`, в котором `type` может быть `MAP_TYPE_HYBRID`, `MAP_TYPE_NORMAL`, MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE`, но не понимаю как его использовать.

Подскажите как создать собственные элементы управления, отвечающие за смену типа карт?

Comment: Ну вы сообщили, что нашли метод. И? В чём вопрос то?
Попробуйте сформулировать ещё раз.

И да, http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html ответит на большинство ваших вопросов.

Comment: Поменяла формулировку вопроса. И да, там я уже была, вопросов меньше не стало. Не вижу смысла добавлять сто вариантов, которые я перепробовала, поэтому если не сложно просто хотя бы кусок кода для данной ситуации.

Comment: Очень мало информации. Ну вот нашли вы метод setMapType, ну попробовали его, почему он вам не подошёл? В чём именно сложность то?

Answer (score 1):

Решила просто переделать с MapView на MapFragment, благо там такие вещи предусмотрены изначально.